# 2d stealth-type collision

Tags: 2d

I'm curious as to how stealth games work. I am working with 2d right now to get the hang of it, and so far I have come up with the following ideas.

1. create a bounding circle around the player/enemy
2. if the circle comes in contact with and object, let's say a crate, shoot out rays 360 degrees.
3. if the ray contacts the player/enemy, trigger something saying you have been found.
4. if the ray contacts the crate, the ray will never hit the player, thus making him "hidden" to the enemy

Naturally, there will be some kind of crazy vector math involved in this. What I am wondering is if this is the right way to go about doing this? Is having rays being shot out every second or half-a-second something that's feasible and won't slow down the program drastically?

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that The Las Of Us used raycasting to calculate collision and animation position for the main character, so it looks feasible with current processing power, now, you mean you shoot a ray every 60th frame (AKA once a second) or that you shoot the rays at 60Hz... Maybe it is clearly stated there but a confirmation won't hurt

Comment: However keep in mind that the only way to find out that your method works is by profiling and finding any bottlenecks that will give you undesired performance.

Comment: I was thinking shooting the ray once a second or maybe half second

Comment: The vector math is not that crazy. Roguelikes do stuff like this (look up Line of Sight).

Comment: Instead of shooting out lots of rays, shoot out only at the *corners* of the crates. See [this article](http://ncase.me/sight-and-light/) or [my tutorial](http://www.redblobgames.com/articles/visibility/) for ways to make a *polygon* of all the areas the enemy can see. If the player is in the polygon, they are visible. The roguelike community has some great variants of this technique for grids; see [this](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Field_of_Vision) and [this](http://www.roguebasin.com/index.php?title=Comparative_study_of_field_of_view_algorithms_for_2D_grid_based_worlds).

Comment: Instead of doing those many raycasts, create a FOV for each enemy. Using vector math (specifically the dot product) check whether the player is in the FOV of the enemy or not, and if he is, just perform a raycast from enemy to player position. If it hits the player, he's spotted and if not, then continue as usual.